# Highlighting a menu item in BottomNavigationView without invoking onNavigationItemSelected method

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` in my activity with `onNavigationItemSelected` listener.

I have two questions:

1. Does `setSelectedItemId` method invoke the `onNavigationItemSelected` method? The documentation says this method behaves as if the menu item was tapped, my observation is yes.
2. If yes, how to highlight a menu item without invoking `onNavigationItemSelected`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Yes, `BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(int itemId)` triggers `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.
2. Use `BottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(int index)` or `BottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(int id)`, then call `MenuItem.setChecked(boolean checked)` to highlight a menu item without triggering `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.